# Can docker on Azure Linux App Service authenticate with the ACR without us specifying the password in the app settings?

Tags: azure, docker, authentication, terraform, azure-container-registry

We deploy a Linux App Service to Azure using terraform. The relevant configuration code is:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "webapp" {
  app_settings = {
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL              = "https://${local.ctx.AcrName}.azurecr.io"
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME         = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.acr_admin_user.value
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD         = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.acr_admin_password.value
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The problem is that terraform does not consider `app_settings` a secret and so it outputs in the clear the `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD` value in the Azure DevOps output (I obfuscated the actual values):
[image]

So, I am wondering - can docker running on an Azure Linux App Service host authenticate with the respective ACR without us having to pass the password in a way that makes it so obvious to every one who can inspect the pipeline output?

The following article seems relevant in general - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login, but it is unclear how we can apply it in my context, if at all.

Also, according to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/36145444-web-app-for-containers-acr-access-requires-admin#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D Microsoft has started working on something relevant, but looks like this is still a work in progress (almost 5 months).

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid you must set the environment variables about `DOCKER_REGISTRY_*` to pull the images from the ACR, it's the only way to do that designed by Azure. But for the sensitive info about the password, it also provides a way to hide it. You can use the Key Vault to store the password in secret, and then get the password from the secret. Take a look at the document [Use Key Vault references for App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references). So you can change the `app_setting` for the password like this:

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)"
```

Or

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret;SecretVersion=ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)"
```

Then it just shows the reference of the Key Vault, not the exact password.

Comment: @mark How about the check? Do you already it and is it the thing you expect?

Comment: Not yet, we have slated the work into the next sprint, which starts in a week, but we will definitely check and then I will be back with the results.

Comment: @mark Any updates for the question? It's already a week passed. I didn't think it's a difficult thing to check.

Comment: we are working according to 3 week sprints. The work item to check your idea is in the backlog and should be slated into the upcoming sprint. We will get there, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Azure Web Apps do not support interacting with ACR using a managed identity, you must pass those Environment Variables to the App Service.

Terraform does not currently support applying a "sensitive" flag to arbitrary values. You can define outputs as sensitive, but it will not help with values you want to hide during the plan phase.

I would suggest checking out https://github.com/cloudposse/tfmask, using the `TFMASK_RESOURCES_REGEX` configuration to block the output you want to hide during your pipeline. If you're averse to adding dependencies, similar effect could be achieved by piping `terraform apply` through `grep --invert-match "DOCKER_REGISTRY"` instead.

@charles-xu has a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62038413/4601453) as well if you want to set up mappings between keyvault and your web app then push your tokens into kv secrets.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible to use managed identity to pull images from ACR.
You may do the next:

1. go to your Container Registry page in the Azure portal
2. Open the tab `Access Control (IAM)`
3. The open `Role assignments` tab
4. Add role assignment `AcrPull` to your App Service or Function App
5. In the `Deployment Center` of your App Service choose Managed Identity for the `Authentication` setting.

Or you may use CLI by following the steps from the official documentation (link below):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#use-managed-identity-to-pull-image-from-azure-container-registry

After you added role assignment `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL`, `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME` and `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD` settings may be removed from App Service's App Settings.